# How to write in ORM rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

working sql is mentioned here

```
SELECT et.* FROM examtypes et
LEFT JOIN categoryexams ce ON et.id = ce.examtype_id
LEFT JOIN categoryexamusers ceu ON ce.id = ceu.categoryexam_id
LEFT JOIN categoryusers cu ON cu.id = ceu.categoryuser_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = cu.user_id
WHERE u.id =1
```

table categoryexam is missing in image. please find the below line

```
 categoryexams ce ON et.id = ce.examtype_id
```

[image]

**examtype**
  `has_many :categoryexams`

**exam**
  `has_many :categoryexam, :dependent => :destroy`

**category_exam_user**
  `belongs_to :categoryexam`
  `belongs_to :categoryuser`

**category_exam**
  `belongs_to :exam`
  `belongs_to :examtype`
  `has_many :categoryexamuser`
  `has_many :categoryusers, :through => :categoryexamuser`

Comment: when giving user_id = 1 want to get the exam_types.name

Comment: do you have relationships between these models like has_one or has_many. refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @AdityaShedge yes mentioned on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help i guess

```
cat_user_id = Categoryuser.where(:user_id => 1).pluck(:id)
cat_exam_id = Categoryexamuser.where('categoryuser_id in (?)', cat_user_id).pluck(:categoryexam_id)
exam_type_id = Categoryexam.where('id in (?)', cat_exam_id).pluck(:examtype_id)
@examTypes = Examtype.where('id in (?)', exam_type_id).select(:name)
```

Comment: Dey, angottum ingottum answer cheydu kalikukayano? May be we can do it a lot more better, if we learn how to make use of JOINS in ORM way!!